# Laravel Envoy Permissions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, devops, laravel-envoy

Ok, so I am trying to call Envoy from a controller function but running into permissions problems that nobody else seems to be getting?

I have installed envoy globally and done a symlink to /usr/local/bin so that my site can see it. But I cannot figure out why it doesn't have permission.

I am running from Ubuntu 16.04, Nginx, PHP 7.0

Any help is appreciated:

```
$result = [];
         $live = false;

         $process = new \Symfony\Component\Process\Process('envoy run deploy --domain="test"');
         $process->setTimeout(3600);
         $process->setIdleTimeout(300);
         $process->setWorkingDirectory(base_path());
         $process->run(
             function ($type, $buffer) use ($live, &$result) {
                 $buffer = str_replace('[127.0.0.1]: ', '', $buffer);

                 if ($live) {
                     echo $buffer . '</br />';
                 }

                 $result[] = $buffer;
             }
         );

         dd($result);
```

But getting:

```
0 => "sh: 1: "
  1 => "envoy: Permission denied"
  2 => "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is the permission for the laravel app user. You should take into acccount that laravel process is owned by a different user (presumably `www-data`) who does not have permission to execute `envoy`.

To fix this, you have to tweak the permissions of the `envoy` which could lead to security weaknesses and time consuming on different deployments.

`sudo chown www-data:www-data ~/.composer/vendor/laravel/envoy/envoy`

**However**, I recommend that you use `composer require laravel/envoy` in your project and execute it from `vendor/bin/envoy`.

Comment: Interesting, I have already tried `sudo chown www-data:www-data ~/.composer/vendor/laravel/envoy/envoy` but had no luck.

I had not tried a local envoy however.

I have found a solution by using: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/ssh

Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by using: laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/ssh